# I accidentally sent my KINDER (BNB token) to the KINDER token contract address. Can I get them back? (I believe I have the source code too)

Tags: msg.sender, build-from-source

I was trying to send some of my KINDER tokens to another wallet I own and somehow I sent it to the KINDER token contract address.

I have since reached out to an admin in the KINDER telegram group. He sent me all this code. I assume this is what I need to find out if its capable of getting them back.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I know the total amount is not a lot, but its a lot to me at this time. I would be grateful to get any of it back.

Attached below is the Binance Transaction Hash and Source code from the admin of KINDER.

https://bscscan.com/tx/0x890727e5ba84c5b7fb0b50e79d468804f97e6e27a7be6210ff84ef9ab83dab0d
https://pastebin.com/b8cFgq7p

Answer (score 0):

I went over 2000 lines of their contact and I saw no function that might return you your token from the contract.

However, their contract seems to be upgradable (or they at least tried to made it such).

Meaning the owners of the contract should be able to upgrade the code in such a way as to be able to return your money to you. However, I am positive they will not bother doing it, as it would require an effort on their part.

Secondly it seems they only "tried" to make their contract upgradable, instead of really designing it that way (Meaning they wanted to be smart, but didn't know how to code it right).

From what I see, (could be wrong), they claim in the comments that their contract is upgradable, but it actually isn't.

Do talk with them (admin, and the contract owners), but as far as I can see, there is no plausible way of getting your tokens back.

I know this isn't what you would like to hear. But I am only telling you what I see from their code.

Comment: I appreciate you so much Sky. Is this the whole source code or do you think it was missing some too?

Comment: The link you gave has the entire contract there. (Whole source code)

Comment: Sky, when you say it appears the source code is upgradable, which would allow me to get my coins back. Who would be able to do this? The developer of the coin or someone else? How exactly do I ask this? I plan on talking to an admin on Monday. Not sure how to word this.

Comment: Some of the contract code/comments indicates they used @OpenZeppelin libraries for upgradable SmartContracts. (But I don't think they had done it right). However, if I am wrong and their contract is upgradable, they could add additional logic into contract that allows them to return tokens back to owners, (Someone would have to pay the gas though) so that should be sorted out. But that would take effort on their part (an effort I am not so sure they are capable off if judging by their code)

Comment: Sky, I just want to make sure I understand everything you’re saying correctly.                                         1. The admins or developers or both can add this code in possibly?               2. When you say it would take effort to add this code in, how much effort are we talking? Just copy and paste some code? Or hours/days to configure it correctly?                          3. Why do you believe so strongly they are not capable, even if their code is beginner.

Comment: To be able to upgrade your contract, you need to make it such (upgradable) from the start. However, it seems they have failed to implement such a capability, at least from what I am able to see.  Regarding the effort from their side, they would need developers who know what they are doing, someone to audit the changes, plus expend ETH to deploy new upgrade. All that would likely cost them thousands of dollars, (you need to pay people to do it). Therefor I doubt they will be wiling to do it.

Comment: Hey Sky, I read somewhere on stackexchange that if the contract has implemented a function which does msg.sender.send or msg.sender.transfer, or even some other address of an account which they control (i.e., have a the private key of. I have found 5 separate areas in this code with that command msg.sender. Can you confirm if this information is correct?